# Use math equation in excel chart label

Tags: excel, charts, bar-chart

I created a excel document for algorithm evaluation, and need to display a bar chart for visualizing, however I don't know how to place an equation to bar label.

I did a same thing with LaTEX and now I have to create another version with excel bar chart, please help me.

This is the latex result

[image]

Comment: Add Data into Excel Cells Eg: `0=[1,O,O]T` in cell `A1` and Corresponding Value `0.21850` in Cell `A2` and so on. and insert a Bar graph and right click on any Bar in the graph and select Add Data Labels.

Comment: without a further trick unfortunately this doesn't make the exponent a superscript ... even when you format a standard T as superscript within the cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- in order to ***really*** get the superscript characters to the chart, use an unicode font
- unicode fonts normally provide a complete set uf sub- and superscript characters ... I used Calibri - the superscript T is U+1D40 - "modified T"

[image]

- write Greek letters either using an Unicode font or e.g. Symbol ... I used Calibri here as well
- your formulae are the vertical axis titles
- your values are data
- select and press [Bar] to create a bar chart

[image]

note that in the first vertical axis title I used the U-1D40-T and additionally formatted it as "superscript" ... no effect in the chart (plain letters behave the same way)